# Using WebClient for Spring Boot integration testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to migrate some integration tests of a Spring Boot application from `RestTemplate` to `WebClient`. Currently, the tests use an autowired instance of `TestRestTemplate`

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

When the tests are run, `restTemplate` is configured to use the same base URL and (randomly chosen) port that the server runs on.

In one of my tests, I login and save the authorization response header value for use in subsequent API calls. I tried migrating this to `WebClient` like so

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create()

var authResult = webClient.post()
    .uri("/api/authenticate")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .bodyValue(new LoginDetails(username, password))
    .retrieve()
    .toBodilessEntity()
    .block();

// save the token that was issued and use it for subsequent requests
this.authHeader = authResult.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```

But when I create the `WebClient` instance like this it is not configured to use the same port as the application.

I tried instead to use a dependency-injected instance of `TestWebClient`

```
@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;
```

This does connect the web client to the server (same base URL and port), however the `WebTestClient` API has quite a different API to `WebClient`. Specifically, it only seems to allow the properties of the response to be asserted, e.g. you can assert that a particular response header value exists, but there's no way to save that header's value.

```
var authResult = webTestClient.post()
    .uri("/api/authenticate")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .bodyValue(new LoginDetails(username, password))
    .exchange()
    .expectHeader()
    .exists(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```

Is there a way to either:

- Create a `WebClient` instance that is configured to use the same base URL and port as the server
- Create a `WebTestClient` instance and *access* the response properties (rather than just asserting them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get full access to the `WebTestClient` result:

```
webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/api/authenticate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(new LoginDetails(username, password))
                .exchange()
                .expectHeader()
                .exists(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
                .returnResult(Map.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get the result as a `ResponseEntity`?
If I call `.returnResult(ResponseEntity.class)` it's returned as a `FluxExchangeResult<ResponseEntity>`

Comment: `FluxExchangeResult` allows you to access the whole response info: `result.getReponseHeaders()`, `result.getResponseBody()`, etc.